# Azure Web Service [Linux] Node version missmatch

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, azure, azure-web-app-service

Does any one have faced problems with Node versions missmatch on Kudos services? I have set Node version to 8.9.4 on AppService/Settings/Application Settings Runtime stack, however, when I open Kudo services and check node -v on Bash it shows 6.11.0, but on SHH (also in Kudo) it appears to be correct version 8.9.4

Does anyone know how to change that Node version 8.9.4 would be correct on Bash as well?

Comment: [Kudu lives in a separate container](https://i.imgur.com/PZXyBp1.png), just ignore the Node version installed in there. What matters is your app container, which has the version that you expect.

Comment: @evilSnobu I can not ignore that, because when im trying to add Github deployment to Deployment Options and use custom ./deploy.sh command. The script takes bash version (which is incorrect) and installs wrong npm packages which causes bad build. :(

Comment: Can you use an absolute path in your deployment script? 8.9.4 doesn't seem to be there, but a bunch of recent ones are, just do `find /opt -name node` in the Kudu console to see all available Node binaries.

Comment: Wait, my bad, it is there, under `/opt/nodejs/8.9.4/bin/node`.